# Trigger function when a div enters another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to coding so I know nothing to very little, but I want to learn. I've been working on this for the past few days and i've hit a wall.Got the function to work with a click but I want to trigger the function with the space key when the green div enters the divs with the function. Can it be done? Heres the code i've wrieten sofar.
HTML

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main')
const rowOne = document.querySelector('.row-one')
const rowThree = document.querySelector('.row-three')
const green = document.querySelector('.green')
let xAxis = 0
let yAxis = 0
let num = 50
let count = 50

function control(e) {
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            console.log('worked');
            xAxis -= 50;
            muncher.style.left = xAxis + 'px';
            break;

         case 'ArrowRight':
             xAxis += 50;
             muncher.style.left = xAxis + 'px'; 
             break;

         case 'ArrowUp':
             yAxis -= 50;
             muncher.style.top = yAxis + 'px';
             break;

         case 'ArrowDown':
             yAxis += 50;
             muncher.style.top =yAxis + 'px';
             break;    
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', control)

let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * num)
function indexText1(e) {
    if(num1 % 5 === 0) {
        rowOne.textContent = 'WIN!!'
    }else{
        rowOne.textContent = 'LOOSE!!'
    }
   switch (e.key) {
       case '90':
           console.log('there')
   }

}

rowOne.textContent = num1
rowOne.addEventListener('click', indexText1)

let num3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * num)
function indexText3(e) {
    if(num1 % 5 === 0) {
        rowThree.textContent = 'WIN!!'
    }else{
       rowThree.textContent = 'LOOSE!!'
    } 
}

rowThree.textContent = num3
rowThree.addEventListener('click', indexText3)
```

```css
#main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 404px;
    height: 304px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}

.row-one {
    outline: none;
    width: 398px;
    height: 65px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;

}

.row-two {
    width: 398px;
    height: 65px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-left: 2px;

}

.row-three {
    outline: none;
    width: 398px;
    height: 65px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;

}

.row-four {
    outline: none;
    width: 398px;
    height: 65px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;

}

.green {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="row-one"></div>
    <div class="row-two"></div>
    <div class="row-three"></div>
    <div class="row-four"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more, the part, when you want to fire the function on the click of space bar and when div enters another div..??

Comment: @jamg, what should the undeclared `muncher` be?

Comment: here [pen](https://codepen.io/ankitcodes/pen/bGoaMQY) I declared muncher but I don't understand what to expect. It always shows LOOSE!! if I click any box with the random number. elaborate on what you want to do with that?

Comment: You do this: `let num3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * num); function indexText3(e) { if(num1 % 5 === 0) { /* ... */ }}`. Did you mean to use `num3` there instead of `num1` inside the function?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to change the control(e) function, instead of "muncher"  it was suppose to be "green" and that should make the green square move around.

Comment: Instead with the click of the mouse. I want the green square to trigger the WN!!, LOOSE!! with the spacebar when it enters one of the divs that has the random number.

Comment: Yes num3 instead of num1. Once a divisible of 5 shows up it triggers Win!! and if not it triggers LOOSE!!.